# Where does Amazon Music store files?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, amazon-mp3

I have recently installed Amazon Music, I am a Prime customer.  Music from my cloud has downloaded to my device (Galaxy S3) but I want to move it to my SD card.  I cannot find the music files anywhere to move them.

Does anyone know where they are?

Answer (score 4):

I ultimately found the m4a files in /mnt/extSdCard/Android/data/com.amazon.mp3/files/Music

The trick, however, is that they are hidden files.  They do not appear when viewing the folder with either the native file manager or RootExplorer (even when "Show Hidden Files" is checked).  They are found only by using RootExplorer to search the device for "m4a" files.

At least now I know they are on the SD card anyway.

Comment: you actually found an .m4a file that you were able to move to your computer and play in a different media player?  everything I'm reading on google is saying that it is stored in a different format that only the amazon player can read.

Answer (score 4):

First check Amazon Music App Menu, Settings (gear wheel icon), tap Storage Location.

If set External, try looking in *Card\Android\Media\com.Amazon.mp3*

If set Internal, try looking in *Phone\Android\Media\com.Amazon.mp3\files\media\Music*

Then usually subfolders by Artist.
And yes, finding them each time is highly annoying! On Galaxy S5 with Android Marshmallow/6.x, I used the standard My Files manager to add a shortcut to the My Files start screen for my Card folder.

Answer (score 1):

On my Galaxy S5, this is the path:

Phone\Android\data\com.amazon.mp3\files\Music\

My phone software, including Amazon apps, are current versions for today's date.

Answer (score 0):

On my Galaxy S4 downloaded music goes to /storage/sdcard0/Music

And streamed music goes to /storage/sdcard0/amazonmp3/temp/.streamcache

Answer (score 0):

Nexus 5X Marshmallow, 
Amazon player download location.
Just using File Manager, using the directory tab not the category tab (did not have show hidden files selected) and literally go to Music folder. All my Amazon downloads were found in the Music folder.

(SD-card)storage/emulated/0/Music

Answer (score 0):

On my HTC 610 Desire running Android 4.4.2, Amazon music files are stored under two different directories on my SD card.

Files from CDs or songs that I have purchased through Amazon are located under:

**This PC\HTC Desire 610\SD card\Android\data\com.amazon.mp3\files\Music\Public**

Files that are perks for being an Amazon Prime member (I don't have to buy them, they are available for Prime members to stream as part of a Prime subscription) which I download for offline listening are located at:

**This PC\HTC Desire 610\SD card\Android\data\com.amazon.mp3\files\Music\Private**

Answer (score 0):

On a Samsung Galaxy s6 Edge, the .m4a files are stored in a the following location:

My Files>Device Storage>Android>Data>com.amazon.mp3>files>Music

You can use "My Files" to launch explorer on the device and drill down to find them.

Answer (score 0):

On a Google Pixel the files are stored in the following location:

```
Pixel/Android/data/com.amazon.mp3/files/Music
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On my Samsung Tab 8.4 inch  SMT 700  the path is:
SD Card/ Android / Data / com.amazon.music / files / music